# react hook form not getting context on nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am having multiple tab, each tabs load different components. In each components I have different set of forms. So there is a generic footer where user can click on save or continue.

So I am trying to use the react hook form useContext, but I am not getting the values.

I have reproduced the same issue on the below code.

SaveAndContinue component

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";

const Footer = (props) => {
  const { formState, handleSubmit } = useFormContext();

  const onSaveDetails = (data) => {
    console.log("onSaveDetails", data);
  };

  const onContinue = (data) => {
    console.log("onContinue", data);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <button
        disabled={!formState?.isDirty}
        onClick={handleSubmit(onSaveDetails)}
      >
        Save
      </button>
      <button disabled={!formState?.isDirty} onClick={handleSubmit(onContinue)}>
        Continue
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

How can I get the formData of each component form when clicking on the save or continue button using react hook form context

Any help is appreciated

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-hoover-bcirh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at your codesandbox. the problem is:

on your `ServiceDetails` and `UserDetails` components you should `register` your inputs using `useFormContext` not `useForm`:

```
const { register } = useFormContext({
    mode: "onBlur",
    reValidateMode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: ""
    }
  });
```

Comment: if is useFormContext, when i switch the components basically shouldn't it destroy the state, I want every time new state so that whenever I switch the tabs the formState.isDirty is false, using useFormContext it remains same. How could I do it ?

Comment: adding a reset on useEffect(() => reset(), []) worked

Comment: @ pedram, i had one doubt, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119666/react-hook-form-using-useformcontext-not-working-with-array-fields . If you know any solution it will be helpful many thanks in advance