# react hook form using useFormContext not working with array fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am having a use case, where I have multiple tabs, each having a different set of forms, and the save and continue buttons are common for each and every tab. So using useFormContext i am able to enable, disable the button state and on click of buttons, I am getting the formState of each tab forms. But when I use array fields, I have some default array items, when I use useForm it shows but when using useFormContext it doesn't work (Tabs/UserDetails.js)

```
 const { register, control, reset } = useFormContext({
    mode: "onBlur",
    reValidateMode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: {
      secondName: "",
      items: DEFAULT_ITEMS
    }
  });

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "items"
  });
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-cookies-biqh8)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score -2):

You need to add a `<form>` element with attribute `onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(yourSubmitFn)}`. This should be the first child of `FormProvider` and wrap all your fields.

When a button with `type="submit"` is clicked, the form will call this handler automatically, so you can remove that code in your footer and handle it in App.js.

Also, `useFormContext` doesn't accept arguments, that's what `useForm` is for