# React hook form separate form and buttons useFormContext

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create a generic popup in Chakra-UI, where I can pass in arbitrary forms, with the form in the modal body and the buttons in the modal footer. I have it all rendering fine, and not generating any errors; but I don't have it working. Neither the submit nor the error checking seem to be doing anything.

The goal is something like this:

```
function PopupForm({ type = 'Delete', isOpen, onClose }) {

    return (
        <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
            <ModalOverlay />
            <ModalContent>
                <ModalHeader>{type}</ModalHeader>
                <ModalCloseButton />
                <ModalBody>
                    // <- form body, based on `type`
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    // <- form buttons, based on `type`
                </ModalFooter>
            </ModalContent>
        </Modal>
    );
}
  
export default PopupForm;
```

Ignoring the arbitrariness, I've just manually put in a simple form to test things, with [react-hook-form useFormContext](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext/):

```
import DownloadEppnImForm, { DownloadEppnImFormButtons } from 'components/forms/DownloadEppnImForm';


function PopupForm({ id, isOpen, onClose }) {
    const methods = useForm();

    return (
        <FormProvider {...methods}>
            ...
                    <ModalBody>
                        <DownloadEppnImForm />
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <DownloadEppnImFormButtons />
                    </ModalFooter>
            ...
        </FormProvider>
    );
}
  
export default PopupForm;
```

And the form components:

```
export const ConnectForm = ({ children }) => {
    const methods = useFormContext();

    return children({ ...methods });
}

export const onSubmit = (values) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('Boo!')
            resolve()
        }, 3000)
    })
}
export const DownloadEppnImFormButtons = () => (
    <ConnectForm>
        {({handleSubmit, isLoading, isSubmitting}) => (
            <Button isLoading={isLoading || isSubmitting} onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                Submit
            </Button>
        )}
    </ConnectForm>
);

export default function DownloadEppnImForm () {
    return (
        <ConnectForm>
            {({errors, register}) => (
                <form>
                    <FormControl isInvalid={errors?.name}>
                        <FormLabel htmlFor='name'>First name</FormLabel>
                        <Input
                            id='name'
                            placeholder='name'
                            {...register('name', {
                                required: 'This is required',
                                minLength: { value: 4, message: 'Minimum length should be 4' },
                            })}
                        />
                        <FormErrorMessage>
                            {errors?.name && errors.name.message}
                        </FormErrorMessage>
                    </FormControl>
                </form>
            )}
        </ConnectForm>
    )
}
```

As I said, it all renders fine. But if, for example, I put "Bob" in the input field and click submit, it neither shows the error message (for min-length 4) nor logs the submit to the console.

Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107866/react-hook-form-not-getting-context-on-nested-component), I thought this would Just Work, though I have used a slightly different implementation with the `ConnectForm` wrapper, based on the react-hook-form [Advanced Usage example](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#ConnectForm).

What am I doing wrong here? Why are my buttons and form not talking to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this **did** Just Work. The problem was more boneheaded. If I put in 'Bob', it wasn't submitting, because it was generating the validation error, but the `errors`, `isSubmitting`, and `isLoading` properties are all inside of the `formState` object, so I needed:

```
export const DownloadEppnImFormButtons = () => (
    <ConnectForm>
        {({handleSubmit, formState: { isLoading, isSubmitting } }) => (
            <Button isLoading={isLoading || isSubmitting} onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

and

```
export default function DownloadEppnImForm () {
    return (
        <ConnectForm>
            {({ formState: { errors }, register }) => (
```